# REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG when using MsgPack Serializer after application pool recycling

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, application-pool, msgpack

We have a WCF service application hosted in IIS 10.

Every time IIS recycles the application pool after 20 minutes of inactivity, we get the following exception when using MsgPack for deserialization:

```
The type initializer for 'MsgPack.Serialization.EmittingSerializers.SerializationMethodGeneratorManager' threw an exception. System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MsgPack.Serialization.EmittingSerializers.SerializationMethodGeneratorManager' threw an exception. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))
   at System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(RuntimeAssembly containingAssembly, Boolean emitSymbolInfo, String name, String filename, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr& pInternalSymWriter, ObjectHandleOnStack retModule, Boolean fIsTransient, Int32& tkFile)
   at System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(RuntimeAssembly containingAssembly, Boolean emitSymbolInfo, String name, String filename, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr& pInternalSymWriter, Boolean fIsTransient, Int32& tkFile)
   at System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModuleInternalNoLock(String name, String fileName, Boolean emitSymbolInfo, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModuleInternal(String name, String fileName, Boolean emitSymbolInfo, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(String name, String fileName, Boolean emitSymbolInfo)
   at MsgPack.Serialization.EmittingSerializers.SerializationMethodGeneratorManager..ctor(Boolean isDebuggable, Boolean isCollectable, AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder)
   at MsgPack.Serialization.EmittingSerializers.SerializationMethodGeneratorManager.Create(Boolean isDebuggable, Boolean isCollectable, AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder)
   at MsgPack.Serialization.EmittingSerializers.SerializationMethodGeneratorManager..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MsgPack.Serialization.EmittingSerializers.SerializationMethodGeneratorManager.Get(SerializationMethodGeneratorOption option)
   at MsgPack.Serialization.EmittingSerializers.AssemblyBuilderSerializerBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass63_0.<CreateCodeGenerationContextForSerializerCreation>b__1()
   at MsgPack.Serialization.EmittingSerializers.AssemblyBuilderEmittingContext.get_Emitter()
   at MsgPack.Serialization.EmittingSerializers.AssemblyBuilderEmittingContext.BeginMethodOverride(String name)
   at MsgPack.Serialization.AbstractSerializers.SerializerBuilder`2.BuildObjectPackTo(TContext context, SerializationTarget targetInfo, Boolean isAsync)
   at MsgPack.Serialization.AbstractSerializers.SerializerBuilder`2.BuildObjectSerializer(TContext context)
   at MsgPack.Serialization.AbstractSerializers.SerializerBuilder`2.BuildSerializer(TContext context, Type concreteType, PolymorphismSchema schema, SerializationTarget& targetInfo)
   at MsgPack.Serialization.AbstractSerializers.SerializerBuilder`2.BuildSerializerInstance(SerializationContext context, Type concreteType, PolymorphismSchema schema)
   at MsgPack.Serialization.MessagePackSerializer.CreateInternal[T](SerializationContext context, PolymorphismSchema schema)
   at MsgPack.Serialization.SerializationContext.GetSerializer[T](Object providerParameter)
```

When I recycle the application pool manually, the problem disappears and everything is working fine. Until an automatic recycle event occurs, the problem is back.

I already force all assemblies to be loaded into the AppDomain immediately after application start with this code:

```
var assemblies = BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies().Cast<Assembly>();
```

Does anyone have a clue about this?

Comment: It's an open source project, so why not pinging its developers on GitHub?

Comment: I have opened an issue on GitHub, but so far this behaviour is not known... I wonder why there is a difference between an automatic recycle and a manual one.